# Auto hotkey script to open all the links of the questions form up to down on Math stackexchange

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to write an Auto hotkey script in order to open all the questions of a specific page of the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions) site. It seems easy at first but I have some problems with doing that:

First I wanted to go on the upmost of the page by clicking on the up arrow:

```
^q::
click,1444,85,80
return
```

After this I planned to move the mouse by same distance then after clicking by middle button of the mouse it opens all the links on new tab, but the problem is that the distance between links of each question is not the same Hence I can't write the script that moves the mouse with the same distance (or scrolling with the same amount) vertically and click the middle button.

Also I tried to move between the links of questions by <kbd>Tab</kbd> button and open the links in new tabs by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. but it also fails because by pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> it moves between all the links (containing Tags of each question) and because any question can have different number of Tags my scripts will fail with this method too.

So can you please help me to do that. Thanks in advance!

---

I forgot to mention that I chose lots of ignored tags on the site. (I hide the questions with those tags but if we want to get all the links of the questions on a page it may get the links of those questions too).

It is a huge list of those tags, Just in case if you need the list, ask me to add them in my post.

Comment: Here is an interesting idea for this interesting question- maybe try opening the inspect element menu while on the page and try having ahk iterate through each question <div> block on the page, use the "edit as HTML" feature to turn each block into code, use RegEx to parse out the part in the pattern of `href="/questions/4144796/find-angle-between-space-diagonal-and-one-of-its-edges-of-cube-with-unit-side-le"`, and then `start` `https://math.stackexchange.com/`+whatever href was picked up earlier. It's a bit involved, but it's the most uniform solution I can think of atm

Comment: A bit late, but here are some screenshots I took depicting the solution I proposed in the prior comment: https://imgur.com/a/AeCqDKj

Comment: @Spyre Thank you very much! It is not late, You can add an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I asked my question on AutoHotkey site [Here](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=76&t=90710&p=400569#p400569). And user @teadrinker wrote a perfect script that solved my problem:

```
^q::
ignored =
(
;Here is big list of my ignored tag
)
objIgnored := {}
Loop, parse, ignored, `n, `r
   objIgnored[A_LoopField] := ""

url := "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions"

Whr := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Whr.Open("GET", url, false)
Whr.Send()
status := Whr.status
if (status != 200)
   throw "HttpRequest error, status: " . status

Arr := Whr.responseBody
pData := NumGet(ComObjValue(arr) + 8 + A_PtrSize)
length := arr.MaxIndex() + 1
html := StrGet(pData, length, "UTF-8")

Doc := ComObjCreate("htmlfile")
Doc.write("<meta http-equiv=""X-UA-Compatible"" content=""IE=9"">")
Doc.write(html)

summary := Doc.querySelectorAll("div.summary")
links := ""
Loop % summary.length {
   tags := summary[A_Index - 1].querySelectorAll("div.tags > a.post-tag")
   Loop % tags.length
      if objIgnored.HasKey( tags[A_Index - 1].innerText )
         continue 2
   Run, % link := StrReplace(summary[A_Index - 1].querySelector("a.question-hyperlink").href, "about:", "https://math.stackexchange.com",, 1)
   links .= link . "`n"
}
MsgBox, 4096,, % links ; this line to check which links were found and opened
Return
```